# Библиотека для создания Excel документов без установленного офиса C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, поиск-библиотек

Пишу программу на WPF и мне понадобилось возможность создавать файлы Excel и записывать туда данные из моих коллекций. Посоветуйте какие есть библиотеки для этой возможности, их плюсы и минусы, скорость работы и как с ними работать? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Вам нужны конкретно возможности Excel-файлов или достаточно простого табличного формата (типа csv)? В последнем случае вам достаточно просто писать в текстовый файл в строгом формате.

Comment: @Gordory конкретно возможности Excel-файлов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В своё время для решения подобной задачи использовал [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML). В принципе всё устраивало. По сравнению с оригинальным [Open XML SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) он более человечен в использовании:

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
    worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
    worksheet.Cell("A2").FormulaA1 = "=MID(A1, 7, 5)";
    workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
}
```

проект до сих пор активно поддерживается и доступен в виде Nuget пакета.

Comment: тоже ранее использовал данный пакет, отказался от него в пользу eppplus, так как при помощи первого не получилось выгрузить n тысяч строк, вылетела ошибка о недостатке памяти, тоже самое во второй библиотеке сработало без ошибок

Comment: Вопрос первый: скорость работы замеряли? Быстро ли выполняет? К примеру для 1000 строк.

Comment: @Sanvirtus не замерял, да и было это довольно давно, лет 7 назад наверное. Мне не очень большие файлы нужно было создавать.

Answer (score 2):

Например EPPlus, позволяет без установленного экселя работать  c *.xlsx файлами (Office Open XML format), [ссылка](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/), 
описание к ней [вот](http://sforsuresh.in/generating-and-formatting-excelsheet-in-c-using-epplus/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, учту.

Comment: @Anamnian, название библиотеки является ответом.

Comment: @Qwertiy [В этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/289324), например, название тоже присутствует, но ответом не явилось. Почему здесь да, а там нет?

Comment: @0xdb, допилил его. Ну правда, ответ с текстом в духе "мне тут текста на минимальную длину не хватило" - это как-то не круто...

Answer (score 2):

Для создания xslx можно использовать OpenXML. К тому же там есть тула (OpenXML Productivity Tool) для преобразования xlsx-файла в код на шарпе, который потом можно дописать до генератора соответствующих файлов.

Comment: *К тому же там есть тула для преобразования xlsx-файла в код на шарпе* — ого, а ссылка есть?

Comment: Непонятно за что минус???

Comment: @АндрейNOP, называется OpenXML productivity tool, лежит рядом с sdk - вот тут оба инсталлятора: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: Круто, не встречал раньше! Добавьте в ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, название добавил, а ссылки майкросовт слишком часто меняет - проще нагуглить по названию.